# ¿como se llama este tipo de indexacion iterable[varible: argumento]?

Tags: python

billete = "Esto es un billete de 500 euros

trocitos_de_billete = []

trocitos_de_billete.append(billete([indice_inicial: i]))

Comment: Hola Harold, en la pregunta enlazada como duplicado y su respuesta se explica lo que es esa sintaxis con detalle. Es un rebanado, en éste caso de cadenas. Lo que hace es obtener una subcadena de la cadena `billete`, desde el carácter con índice `indice_inicial` hasta el carácter con índice `i` (sin incluirlo). `"StackOverflow"[4:9]` -> `"kOver"`.

Answer (score 0):

https://riptutorial.com/es/python/topic/1494/corte-de-listas--seleccion-de-partes-de-listas-
ejemplo

```
billete = "Esto es un billete de 500 euros"
trocitos_de_billete = []
indice_inicial = None

for i in range(len(billete)):
  print(i)
  print(billete[indice_inicial: i])
```